# Python 3: Sympy TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

pretty simple I'm trying to a function where y= x and trying to flip it to solve for x instead of y. I was doing silly mistakes so was going to quickly test out sympy for this function. And I'm getting `TypeError: can't convert expression to float` I followed the documents so not sure what I've done wrong. Thanks.

What I've done:

```
import math
from sympy import solve, Poly, Eq, Function, exp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b, c
print (solve((((math.sin((((x - (a + 1)) / (b - a)) - 0.5) * math.pi) + 1) / 2) * 1) / math.pow(1.00571, (b + 1 - x)) *c,  a, b,c))
```

Comment: Break down your calculation onto several lines of code and store some intermediate results. Then you will be able to recognize better which operation leads to the type error because the interpreter will dump the line number

Comment: @tangoal the expression evaluates fine in general solving y giving it x. I'm trying to express the the expression to solve for x given y. I thought sympy could do this.

Comment: Why `import math`?? SymPy has `pi`, `sin` and `pow`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix `math` module functions with Sympy.

```
from sympy import solve, sin, pi
from sympy.abc import x, a, b, c
print (solve((((sin((((x - (a + 1)) / (b - a)) - 0.5) * pi) + 1) / 2) * 1) /\
             1.00571**(b + 1 - x)*c,  a, b,c))
```

works and gives the following answer:

```
[{a: x - 1.0}, {a: 0.666666666666667*b + 0.333333333333333*x - 0.333333333333333}, {b: zoo}, {c: 0.0}]
```

I am not sure if this is what you wanted.